# authentication using LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap

I need to create an authentication form for a website. So i'm wondering if using LDAP(Store user name and pwd) is a good idea. i've been told that storing users in a database table is a bad idea.

For example use Bind(ldapCnx, username, pwd) to check if the user exist to give access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is a good user store for credentials however LDAP should be abstracted from Authentication and Authorization for the website by using [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) and [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/)